# WSO2 bps : How to invoke a REST service not running on the ESB from a BPEL process on the BPS

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process, wso2-esb

I have setup BPS and have created a few BPEL processes which i can use to invoke services on the Application Server. I have created a REST service on the ESB and a REST service I wrote by Java Spring Boot and I have the problem.
My setup in BPS only can run with REST service on the ESB, cannot run with REST service by Java.
When I use the REST by Java, I saw the log:

"ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.PartnerService} -  Error sending message to Axis2 for ODE mex {PartnerRoleMex#hqejbhcnphrfigtpcgkgif [PID {http://wso2.org/bps/sample}CallRestJava-383] calling org.apache.ode.bpel.epr.WSAEndpoint@3807729c.getParam(...) Status REQUEST}
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.axis2.json.gson.factory.XmlNodeGenerator.processSchemaList(XmlNodeGenerator.java:60)
at org.apache.axis2.json.gson.factory.XmlNodeGenerator.getMainXmlNode(XmlNodeGenerator.java:258)
at org.apache.axis2.json.gson.GsonXMLStreamReader.process(GsonXMLStreamReader.java:162)
at org.apache.axis2.json.gson.GsonXMLStreamReader.initXmlStreamReader(GsonXMLStreamReader.java:108)
at org.apache.axis2.json.gson.JSONMessageHandler.invoke(JSONMessageHandler.java:81)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:359)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:445)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.HTTPBindingHandler.invoke(HTTPBindingHandler.java:118)
at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.PartnerService.invoke(PartnerService.java:264)
at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELMessageExchangeContextImpl.invokePartner(BPELMessageExchangeContextImpl.java:43)
at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelRuntimeContextImpl.invoke(BpelRuntimeContextImpl.java:897)
at org.apache.ode.bpel.runtime.INVOKE.run(INVOKE.java:140)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.ode.jacob.vpu.JacobVPU$JacobThreadImpl.run(JacobVPU.java:451)
at org.apache.ode.jacob.vpu.JacobVPU.execute(JacobVPU.java:139)
at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelRuntimeContextImpl.execute(BpelRuntimeContextImpl.java:1002)
at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.PartnerLinkMyRoleImpl.invokeNewInstance(PartnerLinkMyRoleImpl.java:208)
at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess$1.invoke(BpelProcess.java:283)
at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.invokeProcess(BpelProcess.java:224)
at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.invokeProcess(BpelProcess.java:279)
at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.handleJobDetails(BpelProcess.java:434)
at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelEngineImpl.onScheduledJob(BpelEngineImpl.java:558)
at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelServerImpl.onScheduledJob(BpelServerImpl.java:467)
at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler$RunJob$1.call(SimpleScheduler.java:633)
at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler$RunJob$1.call(SimpleScheduler.java:627)
at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler.execTransaction(SimpleScheduler.java:298)
at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler.execTransaction(SimpleScheduler.java:253)
at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler$RunJob.call(SimpleScheduler.java:627)
at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler$RunJob.call(SimpleScheduler.java:611)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"

Both of REST service is only get information of user from database

"http://localhost:8082/user/id/{id}"

"http://localhost:8281/services/user_service/insert/{id}"

And this is my BPS setup to call the REST service

"<wsdl:definitions name="UserService" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/UserService/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/UserService/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/">
wsdl:types<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/UserService/">
<xsd:element name="userID">
xsd:complexType
xsd:sequence
<xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:int"></xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="user">
xsd:complexType
xsd:sequence
<xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:int"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="email" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="address" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema></wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="getParamRequest">
<wsdl:part name="userID" element="tns:userID"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getParamResponse">
<wsdl:part name="result" element="tns:user"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="UserGetPortType">
<wsdl:operation name="getParam">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getParamRequest"></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getParamResponse"></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="UserGetBinding" type="tns:UserGetPortType">
<http:binding verb="GET" />
<wsdl:operation name="getParam">
<http:operation location="http://localhost:8082/user/id/{id}" />
wsdl:input
http:urlReplacement/
</wsdl:input>
wsdl:output
<mime:content part="result" type="text/xml"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="UserGetService">
<wsdl:port name="UserGetPort" binding="tns:UserGetBinding">
<http:address location="http://localhost:8082/user/id/1"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service></wsdl:definitions>"

So every ideas are very good for me now. Thanks!!!